# Disable --COMMAND-- and --INSERT-- mode in QtCreator's texteditor

Tags: qt, qt-creator

Somehow I managed to get QtCreator's text mode into --COMMAND-- or --INSERT-- mode.

I don't care what it is or how it works. How do I get rid of it?
All I care about is normal text-editing without these strange modes.
One of them lets me select text-parts but not delete them.
 My mouse-cursor is now even missing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

May be, you've enabled `fakevim` in settings. Then, disable it.

Comment: That was it! Thanks a lot. Now there's only the thing with the missing mouse-cursor (it is only missing in some of the files i'm editing).